# Create Line Chart Using danielgindi/ios-charts library

Tags: ios, objective-c, charts, ios-charts

I am trying to create a line chart using the [danielgindi/ios-charts library](https://github.com/danielgindi/ios-charts) by passing on the X axis the time values and on the Y axis integer values representing currency amount.

The time value because it is in a finite interval as I am trying to limit it to 7 elements I first convert it to unix and  check witch one of them is the oldest, and from the newer ones I substitute the older one so I get and array of NSNumbers.

And here si my code and the array data:

```
- (void)addChartWithArray:(NSArray *)dataArray{

    NSMutableArray *xVals = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    NSMutableArray *yVals = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    int maxNumberOfValuesInGraph;
    if(dataArray.count >= 7){
        maxNumberOfValuesInGraph = (int)dataArray.count - 7;
    }else{
        maxNumberOfValuesInGraph = 0;
    }

    for (int cout = maxNumberOfValuesInGraph; cout < dataArray.count; cout++){
        TRTargetEstimation *targetEstimation = [dataArray objectAtIndex: cout];
        [xVals addObject:[targetEstimation dateCreated]];
    }

    xVals = [self calculateTimeValues: xVals];
    int secondCounter = 0;
    for (int cout = maxNumberOfValuesInGraph; cout < dataArray.count; cout++) {
        TRTargetEstimation *targetEstimation = [dataArray objectAtIndex: cout];
        [yVals addObject:[[ChartDataEntry alloc] initWithValue:[targetEstimation.estimationValue floatValue] xIndex:secondCounter]];
        secondCounter++;
    }

    LineChartDataSet *set1 = [[LineChartDataSet alloc] initWithYVals:yVals label:@"DataSet 1"];

    set1.lineWidth = 2.f;
    set1.circleRadius = 6.0;
    [set1 setColor: [UIColor orangeColor]];
    [set1 setCircleColor:[UIColor orangeColor]];
    set1.highlightColor = [UIColor orangeColor];
    set1.drawValuesEnabled = YES;

    LineChartData *data = [[LineChartData alloc] initWithXVals:xVals dataSet:set1];
    [data setValueFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Light" size:7.f]];


    self.lineChartView.minOffset = 0;
    self.lineChartView.delegate = self;
    self.lineChartView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

    self.lineChartView.descriptionText = @"";
    self.lineChartView.noDataTextDescription = @"No history available.";

    self.lineChartView.drawGridBackgroundEnabled = NO;
    self.lineChartView.dragEnabled = NO;
    [self.lineChartView setScaleEnabled:NO];
    self.lineChartView.pinchZoomEnabled = NO;
    [self.lineChartView setViewPortOffsetsWithLeft:10.0 top:0.0 right:10.0 bottom:0.0];

    self.lineChartView.legend.enabled = NO;

    self.lineChartView.leftAxis.enabled = NO;
    self.lineChartView.rightAxis.enabled = NO;
    self.lineChartView.xAxis.enabled = NO;

    self.lineChartView.data = data;

    self.lineChartView.hidden = YES;
    self.leftLineView.hidden = YES;
    self.bottomLineView.hidden = YES;

}

- (NSMutableArray *)calculateTimeValues:(NSMutableArray *)passedArray {
    NSMutableArray *returnedArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    for (int count = 0; count < passedArray.count; count++) {

        NSDate *date = [TRUtils getDateOutOfString:[passedArray objectAtIndex:count]
                                     andDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
        [returnedArray addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:[TRUtils getUNIXTimeFromDate:date]]];

    }

    [returnedArray sortUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"self" ascending:YES]]];

    int minValue = [[returnedArray firstObject] intValue];
    for (int count = 0; count < passedArray.count; count++) {
        [returnedArray replaceObjectAtIndex:count
                               withObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[[returnedArray objectAtIndex:count] intValue] - minValue]];
    }

    return returnedArray;
}
```

And here are my helper methods:

```
+ (NSDate *)getDateOutOfString:(NSString *)passedString andDateFormat:(NSString *)dateFormat{

    NSString *dateString = passedString;
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:dateFormat];
    NSDate *dateFromString = [[NSDate alloc] init];
    dateFromString = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];
    return dateFromString;

}

+ (int)getUNIXTimeFromDate:(NSDate *) datePassed{

    return (int)[datePassed timeIntervalSince1970];

}
```

and xVals data is:

```
<__NSArrayM 0x7fca4b775dd0>(
0,
213,
298,
435,
524,
591,
664
)
```

and the yVals array is:

```
[234234,
123123,
2223355,
22222222,
2342,
121212,
121212]
```

And the graph is showing as:

[image]

Now, the Y axis look as expected but the Y axis is not correct as spacing between points is equal, any idea on what I am doing wrong?

I already tried to change the next line:

```
[yVals addObject:[[ChartDataEntry alloc] initWithValue:[targetEstimation.estimationValue floatValue] xIndex:secondCounter]];
```

by giving a different xIndex but the graph stopped showing altogether on the screen.

Thanks in advance for all the constructive answers :)

Answer (score 1):

I assume you mean "X axis is not correct as spacing between points is equal, any idea on what I am doing wrong?"

It is by design. To workaround this, you need to insert your intermediate date values for x axis, but not insert any data entry for the specifix xIndex. This has been asked on github page already.

You have to write your own logic for `[self hasDataAtIndex:cout]`

```
for (int cout = maxNumberOfValuesInGraph; cout < dataArray.count; cout++){
    TRTargetEstimation *targetEstimation = [dataArray objectAtIndex: cout];
    [xVals addObject:[targetEstimation dateCreated]];

    if ([self hasDataAtIndex:cout]) {
        [yVals addObject:[[ChartDataEntry alloc] initWithValue:[targetEstimation.estimationValue floatValue] xIndex:cout]];
    }
}
```

Comment: so I should drop this line `[yVals addObject:[[ChartDataEntry alloc] initWithValue:[targetEstimation.estimationValue floatValue] xIndex:secondCounter]];` and  "insert your intermediate date values for x axis", can you give example on my code on how will these be achived. Thank you in advance!

Comment: I will give it a try and see what I manage to do, thank you in advance

Comment: where did you got the ChartDataEntry from?  and also the method [self hasDataAtIndex:cout]?

Comment: the hasDataAtIndex logic should be implemented by you, data entry is in your posted code

Comment: you said something that this question was posted on GitHub, can you share the original post link?

Comment: didn't quite understand what hasDataAtIndex is supposed to do

Comment: @LaurStefan it's your logic to determine whether the specific xIndex(date value) has the data. Let's say we have two days: 2016-02-06 and 2016-02-07, so the x value array is [02-06, 02-07]. 02-06 has data then hasDataAtIndex:0 return true, and 02-07 has no data, then hasDataAtIndex:1 return false.